# Convert outlook emails to PDF

Tags: python, pdf, printing

I am writing a code in Python that prints outlook emails. Python will read the email (.msg file) by using win32com.client and then print the email using the win32api.  **How do I convert the body of the email into a pdf document?** This is what I have so far, this code allows me to print the email, but if the email has images or other complicated text it does not work. I think a pdf format will be better to print.

```
body_of_email = r'C:\Users\pythonprinter\Attachments\\' + 'messagebody.txt'
    body_mail = open(body_of_email, 'w')
    body_mail.write(str(message.body))
    body_mail.close()

    if 'print body of email' in str(message):
        win32api.ShellExecute(
                  0,
                  "print",
                  body_of_email,
                  #
                  # If this is None, the default printer will
                  # be used anyway.
                  #
                  '/d:"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter(),
                  ".",
                  0
                )
```

Comment: Take a look at [this module](https://pypi.org/project/msgtopdf/).

Answer (score 1):

i'm trying to do the same thing as you.

Weel, i'm using MSG2PDF (https://pypi.org/project/msgtopdf/) but you need to jump through a bunch of hoops to make it work. I hasn't been working on any other machines that i've tried to run my code on. Anyways, **if you get it to work**, it'll convert your .MSG to PDF perfectly.

After jumping through your hoops, you just need to run `subprocess.run("msg2pdf -d" + " " + Directory)` to convert every MSG in that directory to PDF.

Depending on the numer of .MSG you have to convert, you can also use an API, like ConvertAPI wich gives you a few hundred conversions/month for free.(https://www.convertapi.com/). It's not very usefull to me because i need to convert about 200 e-mails daily. Bummer.

Comment: Does this also capture attachments? I need to archive hundreds of project mails and am lost.